# How to sort an object in JavaSript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort the variable `b` alphabetically but for some reason, I am getting an error, `obj sort is undefined`.
This code is written on a  visual basic form with tags to write js.
the return of the variable `b` is:   Extra,Admin1,Alfa,Manda,Alfa2,LCDDF

```
function JSFORM_Start() {
  var b =JSDLS_GetStr("USERS")
  alert(b);
  var a= b.split(",");
  alert(a);
  a= a.sort(",");
  alert(a);
  var c=a.join(",")
  ss("My users.choices", c)
}
```

Any idea how to do this correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in your code at `a = a.sort(",");`

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), the `sort()` function either takes no parameters at all, or one parameter - a comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it same as follow:

```js
let a=[9,5,7,2,1];
a = a.sort();
console.log(a);
console.log(a.reverse());
```